# Traefik ingress with kind and metallb

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, kind, metallb

I'm trying to setup Traefik ingress in Kind cluster with Metallb for LoadBalancer services using Ubuntu.

I'm not an expert in networking settings tbh.

### Configuration files

```yaml
# kind-config.yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    kubeadmConfigPatches:
      - |
        kind: InitConfiguration
        nodeRegistration:
          kubeletExtraArgs:
            node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 443
        hostPort: 443
        protocol: TCP
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

```yaml
# metallb.yaml
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
    # Got this range from docker network inspect -f '{{.IPAM.Config}}' kind
    - 172.18.255.200-172.18.255.250
---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: empty
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
    - example
```

```yaml
# dashboard.yaml
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: dashboard
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik.localhost`) && (PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) || PathPrefix(`/api`))
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
```

### Commands

```bash
kind create cluster --config kind-config.yaml
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready node --all --timeout=90s

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.7/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
kubectl wait --namespace=metallb-system --for=condition=ready pod --selector=app=metallb --timeout=90s
kubectl apply -f metallb.yaml

helm repo add traefik https://traefik.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm install traefik traefik/traefik

kubectl apply -f dashboard.yaml
```

### Results

Traefik dashboard not available at: `traefik.localhost:9000/dashboard/`

If I do a port-forward for either traefik dashboard service or traefik pod it works fine accessing via `localhost:9000/dashboard/`

### Kubectl Command Outputs

```bash
kubectl get svc

NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>           443/TCP                      25m
traefik      LoadBalancer   10.96.128.168   172.18.255.200   80:32760/TCP,443:30039/TCP   24m
```

Trying to access IP `172.18.255.200:9000/dashboard/` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work mistakes were:

Missing metallb config to use ip address pool:

```yaml
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
    - example
```

And then I found out that `/etc/hosts` doesn't support wildcards domain, so every host rule that relies in subdomains should be declared in `/etc/hosts`

```bash
172.18.255.200 traefik.localhost
```

With these configs in place everything works fine.